# excel vba run time error 3265 item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me with the code below. says the run time error of 3265 and showing this line as error:

Sheets("Extracted Logs").Cells(11, i + 1) = rs.Fields(i - 3).Name

even if I use "Select * From table" same issue still. need your help thanks! I am stuck with the code issue.

error message is : run time error 3265 item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal

```
'Disable screen flickering.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("E12:L1048576").ClearContents

'Specify the file path of the accdb file. You can also use the full path of the file like:
'AccessFile = "C:\Users\Christos\Desktop\Sample.accdb"
AccessFile = "\\MNLDCPWFIS01\CorpStrat-Public\LEADS\CONVERSION WORKING DATABASES\CRM_INC.accdb"

'get active user
Set OL = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set olAllUsers = OL.Session.AddressLists.Item("All Users").AddressEntries
User = OL.Session.CurrentUser.Name
Set oentry = olAllUsers.Item(User)
Set oExchUser = oentry.GetExchangeUser()

Set rs = Nothing

'Set the name of the query you want to run and retrieve the data.
strQuery1 = "select Task_Number, Short_Description, Task_Status, Task_Complexity, Assignment_Group, Assigned_To, Created_Date " & _
"from INC_CRM where Requestor_Email = '" & oExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress & "' order by Created_Date desc; "
    
On Error Resume Next
'Create the ADODB connection object.
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
'Check if the object was created.
If err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Connection was not created!", vbCritical, "Connection Error"
    
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Open the connection.
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & AccessFile

On Error Resume Next
'Create the ADODB recordset object.
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
'Check if the object was created.
If err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Error! Release the objects and exit.
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    'Display an error message to the user.
    MsgBox "Recordset was not created!", vbCritical, "Recordset Error"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
     
'Set thee cursor location.
rs.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient on early  binding
rs.CursorType = 1 'adOpenKeyset on early  binding

'Open the recordset.
rs.Open strQuery1, con

'Check if the recordset is empty.
If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
    'Close the recordset and the connection.
    rs.Close
    con.Close
    'Release the objects.
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    'Enable the screen.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'In case of an empty recordset display an error.
    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset!", vbCritical, "No Records"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Copy the recordset headers.
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count + 3
    Sheets("Extracted Logs").Cells(11, i + 1) = rs.Fields(i - 3).Name
Next i

'Write the query values in the sheet.
 Sheets("Extracted Logs").Range("E12").CopyFromRecordset rs

'Close the recordset and the connection.
rs.Close
con.Close


'Release the objects.
Set rs = Nothing
Set con = Nothing

'Adjust the columns' width.
'Columns("A:L").AutoFit
'Sheets("Extracted Logs").Range("J2", "J50000").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
'Sheets("Extracted Logs").Range("I2", "I50000").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"

'Enable the screen.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

oh okay I got it now. its the positioning of the header of my table. My mistake sorry